# broken line in a table for p{0.5\textwidth} options

Tags: tables

I am working with the following document. As shown in the figure, the compiled result of the table is strange. I think this is due to `p{0.5\textwidth}` option, but I cannot find any solutions. How can I solve this problem?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=30mm,right=30mm,top=35mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath} % math
\usepackage{amssymb} % math
\usepackage{graphicx} % to use \includegraphics{}
\usepackage{diagbox} % to make tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{bm, array, tabularx, pifont}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{0.5\textwidth}|p{0.5\textwidth}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{from the textbook}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{from the articles}\\
    \hline
    \ding{172} p.34 Explaining significance\newline \textbf{fundamental issue}\newline Explaining the mechanisms of high-temperature superconductors has been a fundamental issue after BCS theory proposed in 20th century.& \ding{174} Problem \newline \textbf{ambiguous} \newline For a wave packet with a spread in wavenumber $k$, some \emph{ambiguity} arises in the values of the phase and group velocities because of the spread in $k$, but, for narrow packets in $k$ space, the uncertainties in these values are small \cite{intro1}. \\
    \hline
    \ding{173} p.35 Verbs to present current research\newline \textbf{prove}\newline This paper proves the Riemann-Zeta hypothesis. & \ding{173} Verbs used to present previous research\newline \textbf{indicate} \newline With the increased current, investigations \emph{indicated} that wear is associated with the intensification of the abrasive properties of the metal counterbody surface \cite{intro2}.\\
    \hline
    \ding{174} p.37 Problem\newline \textbf{computationally demanding, an alternative approach}\newline Since the simulation method in the previous researches are \emph{computationally demanding}, \emph{an alternative approach} was needed for this paper.& \ding{175} The present work \newline \textbf{propose, discuss, this paper} \newline \emph{This paper proposes} and \emph{discusses} a definition of internal energy \cite{intro3}.\\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}

\end{table} 

\bibliography{ref}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `tabularx` can do nothing sensible if there is no `X` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not use `tabularx` when you have no `X` column.
2. You should consider that the column separations and vertical lines occupy space; your specifications for column of `0.5\textwidth` will encounter problems since 0.5+0.5 + the other separations that are present >1 so LaTeX is encountering problem fitting your table

About recommendations:

1. Lose the vertical separators, which are ugly, serve no purpose and make the table bulkier to read.
2. (proposed solution) Lose the horizontal lines too, in favor of a `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` which enhances the spaces among table rows
3. apply `@{}` which suppresses extra spacing, before the first and after the last column specifications in wide tables. This allows text to fit in nicely. It's kind of debated on when it is appropriate to do so, and it comes out as a design choice.
4. You should also consider applying the `raggedright` setting to the first column since its contents are usually difficult to justify. I'll leave this as an extra solution
5. Load the `booktabs` package to have the elegant rules (`toprule` `midrule` `bottomrule`) to typeset your table

Nevertheless, here is some code:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=30mm,right=30mm,top=35mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath} % math
\usepackage{amssymb} % math
\usepackage{graphicx} % to use \includegraphics{}
\usepackage{diagbox} % to make tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{bm, array, booktabs, pifont,tabularx}
\usepackage{apacite}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XX@{}}
    \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{from the textbook}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{from the articles}\\
    \midrule
    \ding{172} p.34 Explaining significance\newline \textbf{fundamental issue}\newline Explaining the mechanisms of high-temperature superconductors has been a fundamental issue after BCS theory proposed in 20th century.
  & \ding{174} Problem \newline \textbf{ambiguous} \newline For a wave packet with a spread in wavenumber $k$, some \emph{ambiguity} arises in the values of the phase and group velocities because of the spread in $k$, but, for narrow packets in $k$ space, the uncertainties in these values are small \cite{intro1}. \\

    \ding{173} p.35 Verbs to present current research\newline \textbf{prove}\newline This paper proves the Riemann-Zeta hypothesis. 
    & \ding{173} Verbs used to present previous research\newline \textbf{indicate} \newline With the increased current, investigations \emph{indicated} that wear is associated with the intensification of the abrasive properties of the metal counterbody surface \cite{intro2}.\\

    \ding{174} p.37 Problem\newline \textbf{computationally demanding, an alternative approach}\newline Since the simulation method in the previous researches are \emph{computationally demanding}, \emph{an alternative approach} was needed for this paper.& 
    \ding{175} The present work \newline \textbf{propose, discuss, this paper} \newline \emph{This paper proposes} and \emph{discusses} a definition of internal energy \cite{intro3}.\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}

\end{table} 

\bibliography{ref}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\end{document}
```

And its output:

[image]

With the first column ragged right:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=30mm,right=30mm,top=35mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath} % math
\usepackage{amssymb} % math
\usepackage{graphicx} % to use \includegraphics{}
\usepackage{diagbox} % to make tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{bm, array, booktabs, pifont,tabularx}
\usepackage{apacite}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}XX@{}}
    \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{from the textbook}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{from the articles}\\
    \midrule
    \ding{172} p.34 Explaining significance\newline \textbf{fundamental issue}\newline Explaining the mechanisms of high-temperature superconductors has been a fundamental issue after BCS theory proposed in 20th century.
  & \ding{174} Problem \newline \textbf{ambiguous} \newline For a wave packet with a spread in wavenumber $k$, some \emph{ambiguity} arises in the values of the phase and group velocities because of the spread in $k$, but, for narrow packets in $k$ space, the uncertainties in these values are small \cite{intro1}. \\

    \ding{173} p.35 Verbs to present current research\newline \textbf{prove}\newline This paper proves the Riemann-Zeta hypothesis. 
    & \ding{173} Verbs used to present previous research\newline \textbf{indicate} \newline With the increased current, investigations \emph{indicated} that wear is associated with the intensification of the abrasive properties of the metal counterbody surface \cite{intro2}.\\

    \ding{174} p.37 Problem\newline \textbf{computationally demanding, an alternative approach}\newline Since the simulation method in the previous researches are \emph{computationally demanding}, \emph{an alternative approach} was needed for this paper.& 
    \ding{175} The present work \newline \textbf{propose, discuss, this paper} \newline \emph{This paper proposes} and \emph{discusses} a definition of internal energy \cite{intro3}.\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}

\end{table} 

\bibliography{ref}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: just as `tabularx` needx `X` `tabular*` needs `\extracolumnsep` or just simply use `tabular`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle right… I'm reverting to X columns since I feel them more appropriate in this case. Editing thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're mistaking what `tabularx` is for. What you need is just to compute the column width: remove the padding and the rule widths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc,pifont}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|*{2}{p{0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{from the textbook}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{from the articles}\\
\hline
\ding{172} p.34 Explaining significance\newline \textbf{fundamental issue}\newline Explaining the mechanisms of high-temperature superconductors has been a fundamental issue after BCS theory proposed in 20th century.& \ding{174} Problem \newline \textbf{ambiguous} \newline For a wave packet with a spread in wavenumber $k$, some \emph{ambiguity} arises in the values of the phase and group velocities because of the spread in $k$, but, for narrow packets in $k$ space, the uncertainties in these values are small \cite{intro1}. \\
\hline
\ding{173} p.35 Verbs to present current research\newline \textbf{prove}\newline This paper proves the Riemann-Zeta hypothesis. & \ding{173} Verbs used to present previous research\newline \textbf{indicate} \newline With the increased current, investigations \emph{indicated} that wear is associated with the intensification of the abrasive properties of the metal counterbody surface \cite{intro2}.\\
\hline
\ding{174} p.37 Problem\newline \textbf{computationally demanding, an alternative approach}\newline Since the simulation method in the previous researches are \emph{computationally demanding}, \emph{an alternative approach} was needed for this paper.& \ding{175} The present work \newline \textbf{propose, discuss, this paper} \newline \emph{This paper proposes} and \emph{discusses} a definition of internal energy \cite{intro3}.\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer provided, is a table the right way to display this information?  What about a pair of lists?  That may lead to a more natural and aesthetically pleasing layout.

It's hard for me to interpret how the various cells of the table link together, but I might propose something like:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item[] From the textbook
    \item[\ding{172}] p.34 Explaining significance\newline \textbf{fundamental issue}\newline Explaining the mechanisms of high-temperature superconductors has been a fundamental issue after BCS theory proposed in 20th century.
    \item[\ding{173}] p.35 Verbs to present current research\newline \textbf{prove}\newline This paper proves the Riemann-Zeta hypothesis.
    \item[\ding{174}] p.37 Problem\newline \textbf{computationally demanding, an alternative approach}\newline Since the simulation method in the previous researches are \emph{computationally demanding}, \emph{an alternative approach} was needed for this paper.
  \item[] From the articles
    \item[\ding{174}] Problem \newline \textbf{ambiguous} \newline For a wave packet with a spread in wavenumber $k$, some \emph{ambiguity} arises in the values of the phase and group velocities because of the spread in $k$, but, for narrow packets in $k$ space, the uncertainties in these values are small \cite{intro1}.
    \item[\ding{173}] Verbs used to present previous research\newline \textbf{indicate} \newline With the increased current, investigations \emph{indicated} that wear is associated with the intensification of the abrasive properties of the metal counterbody surface \cite{intro2}.
    \item[\ding{175}] The present work \newline \textbf{propose, discuss, this paper} \newline \emph{This paper proposes} and \emph{discusses} a definition of internal energy \cite{intro3}.
\end{itemize}
```

which then produces
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. If you have code to demonstrate the pair of lists, please edit your answer to demonstrate this and to show a comparison with the tabular form.